# I am trying to calculate someones age, but it keeps giving me an error

Tags: c#, calendar

We had an assignment on school to calculate someones age using an Calendar.
I think I am almost finished but I am stuck.

```
    int todaysYear;
    int selectedYear;
    todaysYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
    selectedYear = kalVerjaardag.SelectedDate.Year;
    txtLeeftijd.Text = todaysYear - selectedYear;
```

This is the current code I'm working with, at the very last part of my code it tells me that it cannot convert an "int" to "string".
What do I do to fix this situation? Thanks in advance :D.

Comment: Did you do any research for how to convert an `int` to a `string`?

Comment: Your IDE is a very powerful tool, it's telling you exactly what the problem is. `txtLeeftijd.Text` is a `string` property and you are trying to assign an `int` to it.

Comment: Note that code in the post *does not* calculate age in it's common meaning. That would be another duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the person's age as string, you could do something alike:

```cs
int todaysYear;
int selectedYear;
todaysYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
selectedYear = kalVerjaardag.SelectedDate.Year;

txtLeeftijd.Text = Convert.ToString(todaysYear - selectedYear);
```

Comment: Yess, it worked! Thank you for the quick response :D.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your code is conversion `int` to `string`, try this:

```
txtLeeftijd.Text = (todaysYear - selectedYear).ToString()
```

In your example it calculate only year, below code will give you year, month and days of age.

```
private string getAge()
{
    DateTime startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(selectedDateTime);
    DateTime endTime = DateTime.Today;
    TimeSpan span = endTime.Subtract(startTime);
    var totalDays = span.TotalDays;
    var totalYears = Math.Truncate(totalDays / 365);
    var totalMonths = Math.Truncate((totalDays % 365) / 30);
    var remainingDays = Math.Truncate((totalDays % 365) % 30);
    return string.Format("{0} year(s), {1} month(s) and {2} day(s)", totalYears, totalMonths, remainingDays);
}
```